# Angular 2+ component load from server

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-template, server-side-rendering

I have angular 2+ project and i have right now 2 component i.e. Home, and About.

Now i want to load both component from server, means when application load it will make request to fetch home component and when user click on about button then it will make another request for fetching about component from server.

is there any way to achieve this requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Angular Universal :

- https://angular.io/guide/universal
- https://github.com/angular/universal

Or you can use the starter here:
https://github.com/angular/universal-starter

Comment: I checked above link but it seems like while clicking on about button it will not make server call for fetching about component. I want to achieve this, do you have any idea about that?

Comment: It is mentioned in the Angular documentation that [the transition from the server-rendered app to the client app happens quickly on a development machine](https://angular.io/guide/universal#universal-in-action). Maybe you can try to simulate a slower network to see the transition as described at the end of the link.

Comment: Yes that is right but if transition happen between server and client then it should be recorded in network tab of browser inspector.

But i don't see any request for component fetching when router path change.

correct me if i am on wrong way